# Create a HTML link to a membership group in a workflow triggered email

Tags: workflow, email, groups, html

I have a list workflow wich do a number of things, including a step generating an email. That part works like a charm. Inside the email I want a HTML link (mailto:) that leads to a user in Sharepoint Membership group. The group has only one element/user, let us just call him "The Editor" in this case.

The employee who receives the email kan respond to the The Editor by clicking on the link, and then the mailprogram (Outlook) starts a new email with the Editor in the TO:-field. The ultimate goal with this is to avoid the need for changing the workflow each time the Editor is replaced with another person. And for people to reach the Editor without the need to know who this person really is.

Change one place, and the workflow still works. Do anyone know how to solve this? I have never seen this done before, but maybe there is a way? I have access to Sharepoint Designer and use MOSS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the user inside a group, it will be hard to locate the user's email inside that group, because SharePoint workflow will not know that this group has only one user, it will treat it as only a group.

What you can do is, make a list for managing the workflow, a general list, with key value pairs, the key would be the Title column, and the value would be a column that you add to the workflow of type Person or Group, and in your workflow you can lookup this list, get the person's email where the key is "Editor", and that's it, if you need to use more users it's possible to add them to this list later.

Comment: Ah, nice! :-) Will give it a try.